# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in php

Tags: php, fatal-error

i dont know whats going one with my code... u use mysqli and when i execute he show this error, some one cam help me pls?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `imovel` WHERE `finalidade` LIKE $finalidade AND `nquartos` = $nquarto AND `tipoimovel` LIKE $tipoimovel AND `preco` BETWEEN $pmin AND $pmax AND `conselho` LIKE $conselho AND `frequesia` LIKE $frequesia AND `referencia` = $refimovel AND `garagem` = $garagem AND `jardim` = $jardim AND `piscina` = $piscina AND `condominio` = $condominiof AND `elevador` = $elevador AND `vistapreveligiada` = $vistapriv ORDER BY `imovel`.`preco` DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($id ,$imagem, $frequesia ,$conselho, $preco); //bind variables to prepared statement
```

Comment: SQL strings need to be quoted. You are using prepared statments incorrectly they should be parameterized.

Comment: If you check for the value of `$results`, you will see that it is `false` due to the prepare failing. Debug your select statement.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#results" ).load( "fetch_pages.php"); //load initial records
 
 
 //executes code below when user click on pagination links
 $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
  var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
  $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
   $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
  });
  
 });
});

Comment: What is that? You should update your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Use the `edit` link under the tags of your question or this link; http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34259442/edit.

Comment: no, someone tell me for show where prepare mysqli and i think is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be closer to what you are trying to do with your prepared statement. With your current execution the SQL is invalid.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `imovel` WHERE `finalidade` LIKE ? AND `nquartos` = ? AND `tipoimovel` LIKE ? AND `preco` BETWEEN ? AND ? AND `conselho` LIKE ? AND `frequesia` LIKE ? AND `referencia` = ? AND `garagem` = ? AND `jardim` = ? AND `piscina` = ? AND `condominio` = ? AND `elevador` = ? AND `vistapreveligiada` = ? ORDER BY `imovel`.`preco` DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$results->bind_param("sssiisssssssssii", $finalidade, $nquarto, $tipoimovel, $pmin, $pmax, $conselho, $frequesia, $refimovel, $garagem, $jardim, $piscina, $condominiof, $elevador, $vistapriv, $page_position, $item_per_page);
$results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
$results->bind_result($id ,$imagem, $frequesia ,$conselho, $preco); //bind variables to prepared statement
```

Strings in SQL need to be quoted, or replaced with placeholders (which is what the `?`s are). With placeholders the driver replaces the values and handles the quoting.

This query also has quite a few requirements I hope you run this on your DB before using here as it may just not have any results returned...

Comment: sorry but what is "sssiisssssssssii" this is necessary?

Comment: Each one of those is one of the variables being bound. The `i` is an integer and the `s` is a string. Those could be wrong, I wasn't sure what your values were... You can read up more on it here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: now show this error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) "

Comment: ohh okkei thanks ist work good ty ...i have one more question...
when i put AND in query this WHERE's need to be all true?

Comment: The `and` requires that both parts are true. You can group it so it affects things differently. For example `where name='chris' and name='john' and year = 1985` would always be false (because name is never chris and john). But `where (name='chris' and year=1985) or (name='john' and year=1985)` would work

Comment: when i put AND in query this WHERE's need to be all true?

Comment: "SELECT ID, imagem, frequesia ,conselho, preco FROM `imovel` WHERE `finalidade` LIKE ? AND `nquartos` = ? AND `tipoimovel` LIKE ? AND `preco` BETWEEN ? AND ? AND `conselho` LIKE ? AND `frequesia` LIKE ? AND `referencia` = ? AND `garagem` = ? AND `jardim` = ? AND `piscina` = ? AND `condominio` = ? AND `elevador` = ? AND `vistapreveligiada` = ? ORDER BY `imovel`.`preco`

Comment: I think I answered your additional question above, no? Not sure what that code is.

Comment: I want to make the query they wore the requisites they were not all accurate ... and he's not doing that ...

Comment: I am referring to the html of the same query SELECT the "AND" he has, has to be fulfilled all right? is that this is for research and it is for the user to go searching does not mean you go searching all fields ...

Comment: You might want to be using `or` in place of `and`. The `and` requires that everything matches currently. e.g. that all 12 columns are `=` or `like` the values being passed and between those 2 values.

Comment: ahhhh okkei and if i have more than one he will use too?

Comment: Yes, so `where name='chris'` would bring back all people named `chris` but `where name='chris' and year= 1985` would bring back all users with the year `1985` AND named `chris`... and as the third example `where name='chris' or year= 1985`  would bring back all users named `chris` as well as all users with the year `1985`.

Comment: yeah its work perfectly thanks so mutch  and 
 sorry again for having bothered you